# reference that minimum makespan on identical machines is NP-hard?

Tags: np-hard, scheduling

I need to cite a reference that the minimum makespan problem on ($>2$) identical machines is NP-hard. I've seen Garey and Johnson cited as a reference, but it I'm not sure which of the problems is exactly equivalent to this one.

Comment: You can simply mention that reduction follows from Partition problem. How about that?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami thanks! Since $m>2$ I guess it is actually multiway number partitioning and the references I found for that just point back to the original work on job scheduling...
I guess they are referring to SS8 from Garey and Johnson, but not completely sure

Comment: All such hardness proofs follow from the subset sum problem. The NP-completeness proof of subset sum problem is given in [CLRS](https://web.iiit.ac.in/~pratik.kamble/storage/Algorithms/Cormen_Algorithms_3rd.pdf) using a reduction from 3SAT. Then, the reduction to partition problem with [2 sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Computational_hardness) and further to [multiway number partitioning](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144991/find-if-its-possible-to-partition-a-set-into-3-disjoint-sets-each-with-same-sum#comment306143_144991) follows from there.